# Finding the maximum area of three XY points in an array of XY points

Tags: c++, arrays, object, compiler-errors

I'm trying to find the maximum area using three XY points in an array of XY points in the form of (X,Y).

I'm currently getting the error `called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer` where the area function is called and I'm not sure why. Also, I have no idea if this function is even close to being right, I'm just messing around at this point. Thanks for the help!

```
double area( const Point & a, const Point & b, const Point & c){

    double side1 = a.distance(b);
    double side2 = b.distance(c);
    double side3 = c.distance(a);
    double s = (side1 + side2 + side3 / 2.0);

    return sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3));
}

double maxArea( const Point a[], unsigned elements ){

        double area = 0;
    double tempArea = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 0 ; i < elements; i++)
        for (unsigned n = 0; n < elements; n++) 
            for (unsigned p = 0; p < elements; p++) {
                tempArea = area(a[i],a[n],a[p]); //error here
                if(tempArea > area){
                    area = tempArea; 
                }
            }
    return area; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double area = 0;

tempArea = area(a[i],a[n],a[p]); 
         ///^^^
```

has the same name as your function `area`. try to use a different variable name, for example:   `maxArea`. Meanwhile, better to change your function name to start with verb, for example: `getArea` or `computeArea`.

One more point:

```
 double s = (side1 + side2 + side3 / 2.0);
```

should be

```
 double s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2.0;
```

Comment: That did it. I'll mark you correct when I can. Any ideas as to if the function will work correctly?

Comment: @user1681673 You mean you are not sure whether the `area` function will work correctly or not?

Comment: The maxArea function. I'm sort of lost on this one.

Comment: @user1681673 Your idea looks OK. Try to make all possible triangles out of the set of points. You probably should change your nested for loops a bit since there are cases when i,n and p are the same and you cannot form a triangle with 1 point only.

Comment: I think I got it to work using the same idea. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should have a look at the way you name your function and variables. they are not very clear.

this area
    double area = 0;

will be used before this area

```
double area( const Point & a, const Point & b, const Point & c)
```

because of their scoping.

Change the name of those two, it should fix the problem.